# Estimated covariance matrices of parameters in lfe

Tags: r

I am trying to back out the estimated covariances for a set of linear fixed effects models estimated using the felm function from the lfe package, but I am struggling.

A small example might explain my problem:

```
library(lfe)
data("Produc", package = "plm")
femodel <- felm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp |
state | 0 | state, 
data=Produc)
```

The femodel has an element called clustervcv, which is as follows:

```
femodel$clustervcv
           log(pcap)       log(pc)      log(emp)         unemp
log(pcap)  3.964787e-03 -7.604048e-04 -0.002501062 -7.940638e-05
log(pc)   -7.604048e-04  4.153134e-03 -0.003951458 -9.809748e-05
log(emp)  -2.501062e-03 -3.951458e-03  0.007265777  1.724270e-04
unemp     -7.940638e-05 -9.809748e-05  0.000172427  6.786427e-06
```

At the same time the summary of femodel looks as follows:

```
             Estimate Cluster s.e.    t value     Pr(>|t|)
log(pcap) -0.026149654  0.062966551 -0.4152944 6.780430e-01
log(pc)    0.292006925  0.064444814  4.5311159 6.806845e-06
log(emp)   0.768159473  0.085239526  9.0117755 1.601430e-18
unemp     -0.005297741  0.002605077 -2.0336216 4.233485e-02
```

I am pretty sure that Cluster s.e.'s in the summary are a function of the diagonal elements of the robustvcv and some degrees of freedom. I just cannot figure out where to dig out the relevant degrees of freedom, and what the function is.

Comment: Try `sqrt(3.964787e-03)` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok blush, thanks a lot lmo for pointing out my stupidity. Seems that I was confused by all the different vcv's that the model object contains.

Just in case someone else is as confused as I was, here's how summary.felm chooses which covariance matrix to use:

1. If the clustering variable (= the variable after the third pipe in
   the formula experssion) != 0, clustervcv element is used,
2. if the clustering variable is 0, vcv is used,
3. and if the clustering variable is 0, and summary() function has the parameter 'robust=T', robustvcv is used to calculate the std errors.